# angular reactive form get the value of formArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a reactive form something like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: [""],
      employees: this.fb.array([this.buildEmployees()]),
      managers: this.fb.array([this.buildManagers()])
    });
```

I would like to get access to the employees array values and the manager array values, as well as the companyName.

Build a javascript object, and store it in a service object.

My question is, how to get the values of these controls?

I know I can get the value of formControlName companyName like this:

`**this.companyForm.get('companyName').value`**, correct?

What about the formArray Employees and the formArray managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the form array values using any of the methods below,

```
this.companyForm.get('employees').value
this.companyForm.get('managers').value
```

or

```
this.companyForm.value.employees
this.companyForm.value.managers
```

If you want to get the particular item in the array, use the index to get the value

Answer (score -1):

```
this.companyForm.value.employees
this.companyForm.value.managers
```

I think this is the correct way, not tested.